# javax.mail: "Connection refused" to smtp.gmail.com

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have a webapp that logs fatal errors (due to bugs in the code, basically) and also reports them via email to a gmail account using smtp.gmail.com:465. This has worked fine for years, and the system is stable so it's a while since I last had a fatal error (Oct 2017). However, the other day I did something stupid while testing a bugfix and it caused a fatal error report. The email wasn't sent and I got this:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I can connect via telnet:

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 74.125.133.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with Gmail's security which means that you have to do some sort of special configuration if you want to use Thunderbird or something instead of Gmail's dreadful web interface. Can anyone tell me what I should do to get this working?

Comment: Are you running telnet on the same machine where your webapp is running?  "Connection refused" is usually a firewall or anti-virus preventing you from connecting.  You won't run into those Gmail security issues until you at least make a successful socket connection.

Comment: Yes, all on the same machine.

Comment: So check your anti-virus or firewall settings.

Comment: Checked. It's a Linux server box with no antivirus software.The fact that telnet connects shows that the firewall is not the issue.

Comment: "You won't run into those Gmail security issues until you at least make a successful socket connection" -- but at what point does javax.mail throw the exception? Since I can connect with telnet, I suspect that I can make the TCP connection, but gmail is then rejecting the login credentials and this triggers the exception.

Comment: Digging into the source, the original exception is thrown from line 1934 of openServer in com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport because the response from the server was not 220 (service ready) -- and yet telnet gives a 220 when I connect. I have also tried port 25 and 587, with the same results.

Comment: "Connection refused" comes from the socket layer, not from JavaMail.  Your firewall could have application-specific rules, but probably not.  I can't guess why telnet can connect from the same machine but your webapp can't connect.  You can try running one of the standalone JavaMail sample programs such as the msgsend.java or smtpsend.java programs just to get basic JavaMail working.  See the JavaMail FAQ for instructions.

Comment: The interesting thing is also that the code which sends the message has not changed for about 10 years, and was working at least until the end of 2017... I will play with your msgsend program and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: If it was working before, that points very strongly to another environmental problem, such as an update to the firewall rules on your machine or on your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was Gmail being cute. The underlying error was an "authentication refused", but it was being wrapped in a "connection refused" exception elsewhere. I finally figured out how to tell Gmail to allow access from an insecure app, and that solved it.